# Priority value meaning

Tags: api, libraries

The library that I'm working on has a parameter which defines priority of a certain process. I want the interface to be as clear as possible, but it seems that different people have opposite interpretations of priority values.

```
1. Lowest number has highest priority (1 - highest priority, 10 - lowest priority)
2. Highest number has highest priority (1 - lowest priority, 10 - highest priority)
```

Which way do you think is more natural/logical?

Comment: For lots of fun you might consider using the negatives with 0 being 'average' priority.

Comment: I think that for any task 3 priorities are enough. But to be on a safe side I'll make it 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are good reasons for setting 1 (or 0) as the highest level of priority and using higher numbers for lower priorities.

First, the priority can represent the order that task(s) should be performed. Number 1 is the first task you do, hence it has higher priority than the second set of tasks you will perform.

Another is that the number of priority levels may be subject to change. In this case, how can you automatically determine what you should do first? If you let 1 represent the highest priority, then your code does not depend on the number of priority levels.

Doing a web search on the string "priority level numbering", many examples show up where the lower the priority number, the more important the task. Some examples use 0 as the highest, some use 1.

This is a long standing convention. Most processor priority level registers work the same way.

I know this does not seem intuitive, so you should make your ordering convention very clear when you work with numbering priority levels.

Comment: It's very intuitive to me. The problem is that to other people the opposite priority numbering is intuitive.

Comment: When you say "this is my my first priority" or "number one priority", it's clear it's the most important thing on the list, so "priority 1" doesn't depart from that. This is the easiest way to remember that the higher number the lower priority.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would never say "This is priority 1" and mean "This is the lowest priority possible". So logically, I would say 1 is a high priority and 10 is low.

However, if I could replace it with an enum, from WhyShouldICare to TheWorldIsCollapsing then I would. And in that case, oddly enough, I would expect the enumeration to run from WhyShouldICare at 1 to TheWorldIsCollapsing at 10.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I find a higher number = higher priority to be more intuitive. And it has the added benefit of extensibility: if you need to add something even higher priority later on, you can simply add an 11 to your scale and not need to change any existing values or go into negatives.

Comment: Sometimes you need to add something which has lower priority.

Comment: +1 - but what if someone needs a new *lower* priority? I'm just voting for higher == higher, though the important thing is that (since it may not be obvious) it also needs clearly say that.

Comment: Another reasoning (opposite to highest number - highest priority) is when you imagine a line of people at a checkout counter. The first one in line has highest priority.

Answer (score 2):

First let's clarify on the term "priority", for example consult [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority):

> Prioritization is an action that arranges items or activities in *order of* importance.

#### The intuitive understanding is based on context and experience

Here giving the context of *priority* usage as arranging items. Semantically connected to the concept of **order** which can be visualized as (vertically) ordered list, e.g.:

1. First Priority Item or Activity
2. Second Priority Item or Activity

In the context of computers Wikipedia directs to *processors [Priority level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_level)* which assigns **ascending numbers** for each level:

> Priority levels authorized are designated (highest to lowest) "E," "1," "2," "3," "4," and "5"

Based on these contexts you can either communicate the meaning and ordering-system according to the *computer-domain* using **ascending levels** or to a more *natural ordering* using **ascending ordinal-numbers**.

Note: the ordering of priority in both cases is ascending - `1` has highest priority with each increment lowering the priority. This also reflects in our colloquial language where we say "prio 1" in order to refer to the "top priority".

See also UX answers to [Is a higher priority a smaller number?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/73445/132146)

#### Find agreement on the ordering and document it

Ask your colleagues and peers, the people that ought to work with the "priority" about their requirements for the ordering.

- from a **usability** perspective on requirement could be that they feel the most comfortable with assigning number when entering this data (intuitive interpretation).
- from a **re-ordering** perspective even sparsely allocated numbers would be beneficial. Given we have the first item A assigned a priority of `10`. When we would like to add another item B, then it could automatically be ranked with next priority `20`. Or it could be moved up, prior to item A, by assigning it a priority of `09`. This approach leverages the free numerical space between 1 and 10.
- **extensibility** could be achieved similar, by having upper as well as lower bounds open.
- on the **user-interface** (graphical) you can represent (visualize) this ranking/ordering by priority completely independent from the internal numerical representation. For example using an ordered-list (`<ol>` in HTML) or simply vertical arrangement. Another way could be the revers magnitude when representing a prio-1 item with 5 stars, where a prio-5 item has only 1 star.

From a collaborative perspective most important should be to agree on a **common understanding (communication)**. Once committed everyone can get used to it and may probably redefine its intuition.
Totally independent from intuitive or meritocratically defined value-system, every ordering (be it ascending or descending) should be **explained and documented** when it appears (be it in source-code or on the user-interface, within project docs or the manual).

Answer (score 2):

If we look beyond the world of programming, processor priority etc., it's clear that the lower the number, the higher the priority. The phrase 'number one priority' is so ingrained that everybody knows what it means. That would clearly indicate that your option

> 1. Lowest number has highest priority (1 - highest priority, 10 - lowest priority)

is the proper way to go.

You can still decide to go the other way around, like [Apple did with iOS layout constraints](https://medium.com/swlh/constraint-priority-in-application-development-d252ac62b56f). Apparently, that never confused me before, probably because they provide clear indicators of what is high and low priority:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When we consider the issue with the *general sense*, it is actually obvious that the lowest number has the highest priority. A simple example clearly shows this fact: When I say **"My 1st priority is something", it is certainly my most important, or highest priority task.**

On the other hand, I have observed from my colleagues that, when they are asked about this topic, people are *prone to* their job or even current work context when deciding. I think provided that we document the Priority value clearly, this will not become a major issue. An example `Priority` property documentation could be

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the priority value (0 is highest).
/// </summary>
public int Priority { get; set; }
```